# Convert a HTML Template into a WordPress Theme issue

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have been working on converting html simple template to WordPress theme so I create folder into xampp - htdocs - wp-content - themes and I create inside this folder 8 files

footer.php ,  functions.php , header.php , index.php , page.php 
    sidebar.php , single.php , style.css

**In footer file i add this code:-**

```
  </div>

                    <?php get_sidebar();?>              
                    <div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end #page --> 
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <p>Copyright (c) 2013 Sitename.com. All rights reserved. | Photos by <a href="http://fotogrph.com/">Fotogrph</a> | Design by <a href="http://www.freecsstemplates.org/" rel="nofollow">FreeCSSTemplates.org</a>.</p>
        </div>
        <!-- end #footer -->
        </body>
        </html>
```

**and in header file i add this code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title><?php bloginfo('title'); ?></title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:200,300,400,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header-wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="logo">
                <h1><a href="#"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a></h1>
                <p><?php bloginfo('description'); ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end #header -->
    <div id="menu">
        <?php wp_nav_menu(); ?>
    </div>
    <!-- end #menu -->
    <div id="page">
        <div id="page-bgtop">
            <div id="page-bgbtm">
                <div id="content">
```

**and in index file this code**

```
 <?php get_header(); ?>
    test
    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I go to my admin page and find this as a theme there and I active it.
But I find it very empty and I didnt know what wrong.

Comment: `wp_nav_menu` required array arguments. comment this line <?php //wp_nav_menu(); ?> and check

Comment: i comment it and its same

Comment: you should comment `get_header()` and `get_footer()` one by one in `index.php` to check from where the problem being started. make sure you have downloaded wordpress correctly and only add new folder in theme folder like wp-content/themes/yourtheme

Comment: i did same and in run time the browser only see the body html header tags but empty inside them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get only blank screen then in most cases there is some misconfiguration in functions.php, do you have any code in there?

I'm not sure if it will solve your problem, but try using wp_enqueue_style() function in your functions instead of echoing your styles in header.

```
function theme_slug_enqueue( ){
   wp_enqueue_style( 'open-sans', http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:200,300,400,600' );
   wp_enqueue_style( 'main-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 'style.css' );
}
```

Put that in your functions.php, and delete  elements from your header.
bloginfo('stylesheet_url') function only gets your main directory url, you are not calling your mains style.css anywhere as I can see. If you don't want to use wordpress standard enqueue function at least try changing

```
<link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

to:

```
<link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url') . 'style.css'; ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

refference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style

Comment: i try this but it give me this error function theme_slug_enqueue( ){ wp_enqueue_style( 'open-sans', http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:200,300,400,600' ); wp_enqueue_style( 'main-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 'style.css' ); }

Comment: hey thanks a lot the problem was i put the get header and footer in index.php i suppose to put in page.php and yes your code for css make the style sheet work also thanks a lot

Comment: You should put get_header() and get_footer() functions in index.php, single.php( - this is a posts template that opens your posts) and page.php, and pretty much everywhere (like category.php, archieve,php, etc.).  It saves you a lot of work of repeating the same code, instead you call your header and footer in every file that needs them. Also don't forget to put wp_head() in your header.php and wp_footer() in your footer.php, this makes functions like wp_enqueue_script and style possible and is used by many plugins, that wouldn't work without it.

Comment: yes i will put all this in my mind i already put get head and get footer in page and index thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress theme required atleast two files to work so first check your theme by including only two files in your theme folder

```
wp-content/themes/mytheme/

style.css
index.php
```

add these lines in your style.css file

```
/*
Theme Name: My theme
Version: 1.0
*/
```

and add these line in your index.php file

```
this is theme testing
```

then run your wordpress website and check

Comment: still empty its drive me crazy :(

Comment: i have checked it and its working for me, have you activated the theme from admin panel->appearance->themes, first activate the theme and then check

Comment: i do this very frustrating :(

Comment: download fresh Wordpress and setup it up with the default themes after default theme work OK then add theme folder as mentioned above, clean your browser history and cache and then check again

Answer (score 0):

Well you have to create a new folder inside the theme folder. SO it should look like this

- wp-content

  - themes
  - Theme-name (lets say bruno)

    - header.php
    - footer.php
    - index.php
    - style.css

Now in style.css, its important that you add these comments.

```
/*
Theme Name: Bruno theme
Theme URI: Your site
Author: Your name
Author URI: http://yoursite.org/
Description: Some description
Version: 1.0
*/
```

These comments will tell wordpress all the information about your theme

Comment: i create inside the themes new folder and i add the cooments in my css

Comment: /*
Theme Name: Bruno theme
Theme URI: Your site
Author: Your name
Author URI: http://yoursite.org/
Description: Some description
Version: 1.0
*/

Comment: Rename the new folder name to Bruno and Try it, it should work

Comment: i change it and it see in on themes in admin appearance theme page but still no content inside it

Comment: To add a screenshot of the theme, you have to create an image called  screenshot.png in the bruno folder. The size should be around 880x660

Comment: in the tutorial i follow the index page have header footer and the test text

Comment: Well yes, your index page is fine. but the data of the index page wont be shown in the admin theme area.